# Call AsyncTask in the parent activity from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an activity with fragment pager and I want to know how to call an asynctask located on that activity from fragment .
**AddActivity.java**

```
public class AddActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager vp;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter pa = new FragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        vp.setAdapter(pa);

    }


    //This void to get All field from the differents fragments and put them into jsonObject
    protected JSONObject createJsonObjectVR () {
        ...
    }

    // Call the Post Method
    public class addVR extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
         ...
    }
```

**OtherFragment.java**

```
public class OtherFragment extends Fragment {
    Button btn;

    public OtherFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_other, container, false);
        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Here I want to call the createVR asynctask in the parent Activity
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**FragPagerAdapter**

```
public class FragPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // First Fragment The main
                return new FirstFragment();
            case 1:
                // Milk (Second) fragment activity
                return new SecondFragment();
            case 2:
                // Housing (Third) fragment activity
                return new HousingFragment();
            case 3:
                //Feeding (fourth) fragment activity
                return new FeedingFragment();
            case 4:
                // Other (Fith the last) fragment activity
                return new OtherFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Comment: from where u called otherfragment??

Comment: new addVR().execute(params);

Comment: @Chelbta just pass the reference of your main activity in this fragment then call it

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar this doesn't works since I'm not calling the asyntask from Addactivity. Also why the vote down ?

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj how To do that ? sorry I'm beginner.

Comment: Show me your code from where you attached OtherFragment in your activity

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj I have updated my code check it

Comment: Use Alpha's answer once

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in your fragment  :

```
((AddActivity) getActivity()).someMethodToCallAsyncTaskInAddActivity();
```

inf your AddActivity:

```
public void someMethodToCallAsyncTaskInAddActivity() {

       new AsyncTask(someOptions_if_needed).execute();

}
```

**One more option**

```
public static  class ASyncronius extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

if you make it static you can call this async task from anywhere

```
AddActivity.ASyncronius  abs = new AddActivity.ASyncronius ();
abs.execute()
```

**Edit 2014-11-11**

if you use fragment in diffrent activitys, then you shuld make shure, that those activitys extends same master class, that contains async method.

```
class ParentActivity extends Activity {

someMethodToCallAsyncTaskInParentActivity(){
***new async execute***
} 

  public class async extends AsyncTask<void, void, void>{
  ***Some stuff***
 }
}
```

Then:

```
class FirstActivity extends ParentActivity{

}
```

also

```
class SecondActivity extends ParentActivity{

}
```

in your fragment

```
((ParentActivity)getActivity()).someMethodToCallAsyncTaskInParentActivity();
```

or if you dont need in that other activity use async task, then just do some thing like this:

```
try{
 ((FirstActivity)getActivity()).someMethodToCallAsyncTaskInParentActivity();
} catch( Exception e) {
   // this is not needed activity
}
```

Comment: Yes it work's thank's but Is there any others method?

Comment: @Alpha do you Know how to get Value of different field from the AddActivity When user click on the button I tried to do something like this `public void callAsynkTask() {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.visitDateFiled);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
    }` but the EditText is always null

Comment: @Alpha for the seconde solutin it doesn't works because I have some dialogProgress so I can't use static

Comment: @Alpha if there's any way to replace this `((AddActivity) getActivity())` by dynamic expression Like `((ParentActivity) getActivity())` because the same fragment is used by to different acitivty AddActivity and EditActivity

Comment: make ParentActivity which have only your Asynctask then Those difrent activitys you use for fragment, make extend not Activity  but ParentActivity, then you can use your line of code. "((ParentActivity) getActivity())"

Comment: dialogProgress ?   Just in Async construtor put Activity Context  (for fragment : new Async(getActivity(), someOtherStuff).execute(moreStuff); )       and then use it while creating dialogProgress.