# how can rerun Asynctask inside fragment from recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have fragment with Asynctask class which needs to Re-Run the Asynctask from my Recyclerview adapter class.

**Note** : I want re run asynctask inside of `viewHolder.buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` in onBindViewHolder and when use this line.

> `new maghalat.GetContacts().execute(); //maghalt is name of fragment contain GetContacts asynctask function`

Give me red line under this line without any suggestion

this is my adapter :

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    List<jsonContent> jcontent;



    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<jsonContent> jcontent) {

        this.context=context;
        this.jcontent=jcontent;

    }



    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

       View view ;
        if(i == R.layout.card_row) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        }else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button_card, viewGroup, false);
        }
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder,int i) {

        if(i == jcontent.size()) {

            viewHolder.buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

         //try This 

                            ((maghalat )context).asyncRun();


                }
            });
            viewHolder.buttonprev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "pre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            viewHolder.go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.get(i-1).pages));


        }
        else {

            viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);

            Picasso.with(context).load(jcontent.get(i).imgurl).resize(300, 400).into(viewHolder.imageView);

        }
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return jcontent.size()+1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == jcontent.size()) ? R.layout.button_card : R.layout.card_row;
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView title,pages;

        private ImageView imageView;

        private Button buttonnext,buttonprev,go;

        private CardView cardView;

        private EditText editText;



        public ViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);



           title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);

            buttonnext =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.next);
            buttonprev=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.prev);
            go=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.go);

            editText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_go_page);

            cardView=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cvv);

            pages=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number_pages);

        }
    }
}
```

this is my fragment  :

```
public class maghalat extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private View myFragmentView;

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private int numpage=0;

    public int sag;

    private String url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(sag)+"/?json=get_posts";

    List<jsonContent> listcontent=new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maghalat, container, false);


        if(isNetworkConnected()) {
            asyncRun();
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "دستگاه شما به اینترنت متصل نیست!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return myFragmentView;
    }


    public void asyncRun(){
           new GetContacts().execute();
          }

           public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    // Showing progress dialog
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

                    sag=numpage+1;
                    // Making a request to url and getting response
                    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

                    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                    if (jsonStr != null) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                            int id=jsonObj.getInt("pages");


                            JSONArray posts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                                jsonContent jsonContent=new jsonContent();

                                jsonContent.title=c.getString("title");

                                //img
                               JSONObject post_img=c.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                                for (int j=0;j<post_img.length();j++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject v=post_img.getJSONObject("mom-portfolio-two");
                                    jsonContent.imgurl=v.getString("url");
                                }
                                jsonContent.pages=id;
                                listcontent.add(jsonContent);

                            }




                        } catch (final JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    adapter=new DataAdapter(getActivity(),listcontent);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }


    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @kunu dos matter ? i define my issue clear

Comment: @erfan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779273/call-asynctask-in-the-parent-activity-from-fragment


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822697/call-inner-asynctask-from-outside-fragment

Comment: @Kunu lookat my edited question

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS lookat my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DataAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
List<jsonContent> jcontent;
private maghalat fragment;



public DataAdapter(Context context, List<jsonContent> jcontent, maghalat frag) {

    this.context=context;
    this.jcontent=jcontent;
    this.fragment = frag;
}



 @Override
 public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)   {

   View view ;
    if(i == R.layout.card_row) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
    }else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button_card, viewGroup, false);
    }
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder,int i) {

    if(i == jcontent.size()) {

        viewHolder.buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

     //try This 

                        (fragment).asyncRun();


            }
        });
        viewHolder.buttonprev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "pre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        viewHolder.go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        viewHolder.pages.setText(Integer.toString(jcontent.get(i-1).pages));


    }
    else {

        viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);

        Picasso.with(context).load(jcontent.get(i).imgurl).resize(300, 400).into(viewHolder.imageView);

    }
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return jcontent.size()+1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == jcontent.size()) ? R.layout.button_card :   R.layout.card_row;
}


 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView title,pages;

    private ImageView imageView;

    private Button buttonnext,buttonprev,go;

    private CardView cardView;

    private EditText editText;



    public ViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);



       title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);

        buttonnext =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        buttonprev=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.prev);
        go=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.go);

        editText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_go_page);

        cardView=(CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.cvv);

        pages=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number_pages);

    }
}
}
```

Your Fragment

```
  public class maghalat extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DataAdapter adapter;
private View myFragmentView;

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private int numpage=0;

public int sag;

private String url = "http://memaraneha.ir/category/%d9%85%d9%82%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d8%aa/page/"+String.valueOf(sag)+"/?json=get_posts";

List<jsonContent> listcontent=new ArrayList<>();



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maghalat, container, false);


    if(isNetworkConnected()) {
        asyncRun();
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "دستگاه شما به اینترنت متصل نیست!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return myFragmentView;
}


public void asyncRun(){
       new GetContacts().execute();
      }

       public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

                sag=numpage+1;
                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                        int id=jsonObj.getInt("pages");


                        JSONArray posts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                            jsonContent jsonContent=new jsonContent();

                            jsonContent.title=c.getString("title");

                            //img
                           JSONObject post_img=c.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            for (int j=0;j<post_img.length();j++)
                            {
                                JSONObject v=post_img.getJSONObject("mom-portfolio-two");
                                jsonContent.imgurl=v.getString("url");
                            }
                            jsonContent.pages=id;
                            listcontent.add(jsonContent);

                        }




                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                pDialog.dismiss();

                recyclerView=(RecyclerView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                adapter=new DataAdapter(getActivity(),listcontent,maghalat.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }


private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        // There are no active networks.
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
}
```

Comment: do that but give error lookat my error pic i edit my question

Comment: give error from this line : give red line from maghalat (expression expected) inside adapter=new DataAdapter(getActivity(),listcontent,maghalat);

Comment: @erfan
sorry i missed

adapter=new DataAdapter(getActivity(),listcontent,maghalat.this);

Comment: when click button Progress Dialog show and never dismiss

Comment: debug and check whether your doInBackground gets reponse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131236/discussion-between-maharith-aditya-s-s-and-erfan).

Comment: your answer was correct . that issue for progress dialog not dis miss was for emulator run app in real device and problem solve!

Comment: dont know how give me negative vote for my question I will be grateful if you give me positive vote to my question